# setTimeout doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

I've made a program that does some processing on the user input. But, instead of processing the input as the user types, I want it to be processed say 1 second after the user has stopped typing.

I tried using **setTimeout()** but this is the problem I'm facing :

1)
When I write the function name in quotes, it works after the time specified.

**Code :**

```
function test_function(input, data) {

$('#write_on_me').keyup(function() {
clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout("console.log('do something')", 1000); 
});

$('#write_on_me').keydown(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        console.log('clear timer');
});

}

test_function($('#write_on_me'));
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39huz7v8/)

2) When I write the function without quotes, it keeps on processing as I type.

**Code :**

```
function test_function(input, data) {

$('#write_on_me').keyup(function() {
clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(console.log('do something'), 1000); 
});

$('#write_on_me').keydown(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        console.log('clear timer');
});

}

test_function($('#write_on_me'));
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nk846866/1/)

**NOTE :** 
The actual function which does the processing cannot be called within quotes as it is enclosed within an anonymous function and gives an "**Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined**" error if called with quotes.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
timer = setTimeout(console.log('do something'), 1000);
```

**calls** `console.log('do something')` and passes its return value into `setTimeout`, just like `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

Instead, pass a function reference into it:

```
timer = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('do something');
}, 1000);
```

If your "other function" doesn't use its arguments, you can just refer to it directly:

```
timer = setTimeout(otherFunctionName, 1000);
```

If it uses arguments, either use an anonymous wrapper as above, or look at [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).